# jquery plugin or c# code to summarize text based on keywords

Tags: c#, jquery, text-analysis

if i'm showing the user search results in a page is there any jquery plugin or some c# code for summarizing the text based on the keywords user searched for ?

for example if the text is :

```
some very very very [ some words here ] very very very long text
```

and the user is searching for "words" it should turn into :

```
... very [ some **words** here ] very ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET you can use `<summary>` tag by applying your own logic as per your requirement.

Refer following link for this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d6dt3kf.aspx

Or

With external tools like [extractor](http://www.dbi-tech.com/productPage_Extractor.aspx).

It can be also done with Jquery as follows:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.summarize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  // simple example, using all default options
  /***** apply the summarize() method to the "containing" element ****/
  $('div.expandable').summarize(); 

});
</script>
```

For this you will have to download [Jquery Plugin](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/summarize/).

Hope Its helpful.

Comment: tanx for your answer but the link from msdn is about comenting your code and summary tag as a description for function ...
and the jquery plugin just clips the text ... i need some code to summarize based on provided keywords ...